# Difference in passing LinkList and LinkList.head

Tags: java, linked-list

I've written a code to add two integers stored seperately in LinkedList.
eg List1 has number 255 stored in reverse order

List1 : 5->5->2

And same goes for List2 let's say it's 999

List2 : 9->9->9

The expected answer is 255+999 = 1254

Ans : 4->5->2->1 (It's reverse order)

**Code**

```
public class imacoder{

class LinkList<T>{
    imacoder.LinkList<T> next;
    T data;
    imacoder.LinkList<T> head;

    public LinkList(T data){
        head = this;
        this.data = data;
    }

    public LinkList(){

    }

    public void printall(){
        if(head==null){
            System.out.println("Null list");
            return;
        }
        imacoder.LinkList<T> temp = head;
        while(temp.next!=null){
            System.out.print(temp.data + "->");
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        System.out.println(temp.data);
    }

    public void insert(T data){
        if (head==null){
            head = new imacoder().new LinkList(data);

        }else{
            imacoder.LinkList<T> temp = head;
            while(temp.next!=null)
                temp = temp.next;
            temp.next = new imacoder.LinkList<T>(data);
        }
    }

}


public static void addTwoLists(imacoder.LinkList one, imacoder.LinkList two){
    int carry = 0;
    LinkList temp = one;
    LinkList res = new imacoder().new LinkList();

    while(one!=null || two!=null){
        int oneVal, twoval;

        if(one==null)
            oneVal = 0;
        else
            oneVal = (int)one.data;  //NullPointerException over here

        if(two==null)
            twoval = 0;
        else
            twoval = (int)two.data;
        int ans = 0;
        if(carry==0){
            ans = oneVal + twoval;
            if(ans>9){
                carry = 1;
                ans = ans%10;
                res.insert(ans);
            }else{
                carry = 0;
                res.insert(ans);
            }

        }else{
            ans = oneVal + twoval + carry;
            if(ans>9){
                carry = 1;
                ans = ans%10;
                res.insert(ans);
            }else{
                carry = 0;
                res.insert(ans);
            }
        }
        if(one!=null)
            one = one.next;
        if(two!=null)
            two = two.next;
    }

    if(carry!=0){
        res.insert(carry);
    }
    res.printall();
}
}
```

**What's wrong?**

1. When I make the call to function like this :
   `addTwoLists(ListOne, ListTwo);` The code terminated with a NullPointerExcpetion at one.data() (Indicated in above code) , even though one is not NULL.
2. When I make the call to function like this :
   `addTwoLists(ListOne.head, ListTwo.head);` Everything runs perfectly fine, no errors at all, Can anyone tell me why does this happen? Since I'am equating LinkList and head (you can see it in the constructor) both should work OK, but it doesnt seem so apparently.

Comment: @RC. I've previously checked if the list is null, if it is not only then I have tried to cast the integer, so how is that possible that the list is not null but the integer inside it is?

Comment: @RC. Thanks, actually I was creating a linkedList as new LinkList(null) and then appending new nodes to it using insert. Hence the first node's data is null and the preceding nodes are filled. That's why I was getting NPE. You can post this into answer box so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cast a null `Integer` to `int` you get a `NullPointerException`.
So if somewhere you use `new LinkList(null)`, the list is not null but its data is.

(As a side note, you should make `LinkList` `static`)